# Apply condition on join statement in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am facing a problem with my codeigniter mysql query. The problem is i want to introduce a if condition on join statement, If that join doesn't return data then join another table.
for example :

```
$this->db->select(*);
if(!$this->db->join(XYZ,XYZ.id=abc.id)){
   $this->db->join(PQR,PQR.id=abc.id)
}
```

I want something like this, Is there any way to apply this approach.
Thanks

Comment: You can build your own query and run it like `$this->db->query('query here');`

Comment: Thanx, butproblem is not with query, problem is how to apply condition on join statement either in custom query or CI query.

Answer (score 0):

Take reference of my example,it may help you out

```
$this->db->select(*);
$this->db->set('tbl1.user_time_index', "CASE WHEN tbl1.status = 'OK' THEN tbl1.emp_time_index ELSE tbl2.user_time_index END", FALSE);
$this->db->where('tbl1.user_id', 100);
```

Here CASE statement is used which works as if{}else{} statement